# TransactionScope and Npgsql - Prepared Transaction Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, transactionscope

I have following code:

```
//...
using (TransactionScope tScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection myConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(_MyConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();

                    //...

                    tScope.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
//...
```

The problem is, when some error occurred transactionscope do rollback, but, on the PostgreSQL server I have prepared transaction. And applications can not work anything with database server until I delete prepared transaction manualy.

Any solution?

BTW, I use Npgsql version: 2.0.11.91

Best regards

Comment: I just download new version Npgsql2.0.11.92 and it seams that there is no prepared transaction with this version...or, there is something else...

Comment: There is no tScope.Complete() call in your code if an exception is thrown. Should there be?